# PuLP を使ったコードの実行時にエラー: PulpSolverError

Tags: python

Pythonによる図形詰込みアルゴリズム入門
http://www.orsj.or.jp/archive2/or63-12/or63_12_762.pdf

を参考に下記プログラム（エラーコメントの後）を試しています。n = 11はうまく行きますが、n = 12はエラーになります。エラー解消できますか？

**エラーメッセージ**

```
PulpSolverError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-fb1f7af9cbf3> in <module>
     40 solver = PULP_CBC_CMD(presolve=1,fracGap = 0,options = ['maxsol 10'],maxSeconds=100)
     41 
---> 42 status=m.solve(solver)
     43 
     44 # 時間計測終了

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pulp\pulp.py in solve(self, solver, **kwargs)
   1669         #time it
   1670         self.solutionTime = -clock()
-> 1671         status = solver.actualSolve(self, **kwargs)
   1672         self.solutionTime += clock()
   1673         self.restoreObjective(wasNone, dummyVar)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pulp\solvers.py in actualSolve(self, lp, **kwargs)
   1365     def actualSolve(self, lp, **kwargs):
   1366         """Solve a well formulated lp problem"""
-> 1367         return self.solve_CBC(lp, **kwargs)
   1368 
   1369     def available(self):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pulp\solvers.py in solve_CBC(self, lp, use_mps)
   1432             pipe.close()
   1433         if not os.path.exists(tmpSol):
-> 1434             raise PulpSolverError("Pulp: Error while executing "+self.path)
   1435         if use_mps:
   1436             lp.status, values, reducedCosts, shadowPrices, slacks = self.readsol_MPS(

PulpSolverError: Pulp: Error while executing C:\Users\mes83341\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pulp\solverdir\cbc\win\32\cbc.exe
```

**ソースコード**

```
from pulp import *
import time
n = 11
w = [9.1, 4.2, 4.3, 7.4, 5.9,5.8,5.7,5.6,5.5,7.5,4.5,3.3,2.5,8.6,1.5]
h = [4.1, 10.2, 9.3, 9.4, 10.5,5.6,5.7,5.8,5.9,9.1, 4.2, 4.3, 7.4, 5.9,5.8]
W = 20
UB = 50
m = LpProblem( sense= LpMinimize)

x=[LpVariable("x%d" %i, lowBound =0, upBound = W, cat = 'Integer') for i in range(n)] ###
y=[LpVariable("y%d" %i, lowBound =0, upBound = UB, cat = 'Integer') for i in range(n)] ###

u=[[LpVariable("u%d%d" %(i,j),cat= LpBinary ) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
v=[[LpVariable("v%d%d" %(i,j),cat= LpBinary ) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
H=LpVariable("H")
m += H
for i in range(n):
  for j in range(n):
    m += x[i]+w[i] <= x[j] + W*(1-u[i][j])
    m += y[i]+h[i] <= y[j] + UB*(1-v[i][j])
    if i < j:
      m += u[i][j]+u[j][i] +v[i][j]+v[j][i] >= 1
for i in range(n):
  m += x[i] <= W-w[i]
  m += y[i] <= H-h[i]

# 時間計測開始
time_start = time.perf_counter()   
print(time_start)

solver = PULP_CBC_CMD(presolve=1,fracGap = 0.5,options = ['maxsol 10'],maxSeconds=100)  

status=m.solve(solver)

# 時間計測終了
time_stop = time.perf_counter()   
ttt=time_stop-time_start
print(ttt)

print("Obj:",  value(m.objective))
print ("Status", pulp.LpStatus[status])

UB=value(m.objective)+1##############

for i in range(n):
  print("Box", i, ":", value(x[i]), value(y[i]))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure ()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111 ,aspect='equal')

W1,H = W,UB
ax.set_xlim ([0,W1])

ax.set_ylim ([0,H])

for i in range(n):

 a,b,c,d = value(x[i]),value(y[i]),w[i],h[i]

 rect = plt.Rectangle((a,b),c,d,fc="burlywood",ec="black")

 ax.add_patch(rect)

for i in range(n):
 a,b,c,d = value(x[i]),value(y[i]),w[i],h[i]
 rect = plt.Rectangle((a,b),c,d,fc="burlywood",ec="black")
 ax.add_patch(rect)
 ax.text((2*a+c)/2, (2*b+d)/2, i, size = 8, color = "blue")

fig.savefig ("picture .eps")
```

Answer (score 1):

別ルートで回答をもらいました。

変数名が被るのが原因でした．
u(1,11) と　u(11,1) が両方 u111になります．n=１２で初めて起きます．
例えば，コード下記のように変更すると動きました．
（%d%dの間にアンダースコア（なんでも良い）を入れる）

もとのコード

```
u=[[LpVariable("u%d%d" %(i,j),cat= LpBinary ) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
v=[[LpVariable("v%d%d" %(i,j),cat= LpBinary ) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
```

修正したコード

```
u=[[LpVariable("u%d_%d" %(i,j),cat= LpBinary ) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
v=[[LpVariable("v%d_%d" %(i,j),cat= LpBinary ) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

変数名の被りの一覧は下記のコードで確認できます。

```py
from collections import Counter
variables = [v.name for v in m.variables()]
counter = Counter(variables)
for k, v in counter.items():
    if v > 1:
        print('Dupulicate', k, v)
```